# AngularJs - $httpProvider.interceptors multiple responseError

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have responseError handler for 401 error. The HTTP interceptor will  ask in the modal user to authenticate and continue to retry the HTTP request. But the problem is if I have more than one failed request interceptor showing me more than one modal and I need to authenticate few times. How can I make retry all HTTP requests after I authenticated in first request?

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector, Auth) {
    return {
        responseError: function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {

                return Auth.authenticate().then(function() {
                    return $injector.get('$http')(rejection.config);
                });                    
            }

            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});

.factory('Auth', function($injector) {
return {
    authenticate: function() {
        var $uibModal = $injector.get('$uibModal');

        var modal = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/authenticateModal.html',
            controller: 'AuthenticateModalController',
        });

        return modal.result.then(function() {
            // success
        });
    }
}
});  



.controller('AuthenticateModalController', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http, Auth) { 
$scope.submit = function() {        
    Auth.login({
          'email': $scope.email,
          'password': $scope.password
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('error');
    });
};
})
```

Comment: Where is the code that handles the rejected promise and the modal?

Comment: @tyler, Modal added. You don't need rejected promise cause if it failed all requests will fail and it's fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want 1 modal for multiple calls to your `Auth` factory, you should define it so that the same modal instance can be accessed each time:

```
.factory('Auth', function($injector) {
    var $uibModal = $injector.get('$uibModal');
    var modal
    return {
        authenticate: function() {
            if (!modal) {
                modal = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: '/authenticateModal.html',
                    controller: 'AuthenticateModalController',
                });
            }

            return modal.result.then(function() {
                // success
            });
        }
    }
});
```